# Ant:Executing a java program from ant and storing the returned value

Tags: java, ant

I am a new to Ant. I am basically trying to execute a java program from ant. I have managed to get that working. However, I am not sure how to capture the value returned by the program in ant in order to use it within the ant file for further operations.

build.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project default="run" name="Experiment 1">
    <property name="shimura" value="Danzo!!!"/>
    <target name="run" depends="compile">
        <java classname="com.sim.expt.Demo">
            <classpath path="./staging" />
            <arg line="${shimura}"/>
        </java>
    </target>
    <target name="compile">
        <javac srcdir="./src" includeantruntime="false" destdir="./staging" />
    </target>
</project>
```

Java Program:

```
package com.sim.expt;

public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String name=args[0];
        System.out.println("Nani!!!!!!!"+name);
    }

}
```

Comment: Ant is a build tool. Is the "return value" you expect to use here the String `"Nani!!!!!Danzo!!!"`? What is the ultimate reason for trying to do this, because there may well be better ways to achieve the same thing? (such as in this simple case creating another property)

Comment: What Java version are you using? Since Java 11 simple programs with just one class can be launched with `java Demo.java` command.

Comment: I am just experimenting with Ant. Basically what I would like to know is how to pass variables from an ant file to a java program and store the value returned by the java program.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `outputproperty` attribute, as detailed at https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/java.html

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project default="run" name="Experiment 1">
    <property name="shimura" value="Danzo!!!"/>
    <target name="run" depends="compile">
        <java classname="com.sim.expt.Demo" outputproperty="myprop">
            <classpath path="./staging" />
            <arg line="${shimura}"/>
        </java>
    </target>
    <target name="compile">
        <javac srcdir="./src" includeantruntime="false" destdir="./staging" />
    </target>
</project>
```

Then `${myprop}` will contain the output from stdout and stderr (unless separately redirected).

Comment: This. Put `<echo>${myprop}</echo>` after the `</java>` to see it, for example.